# 'Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe')

Tags: python, post, python-requests, vcenter, esx

I am trying to 'POST' several ~512 MB vmdk files to an ESX host, however, after first file is POSTed my program starts failing error with the following error:

```
'Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe')
```

I have tried increasing the request timeout, but the script kept running for 17 hours and and the second vmdk did not get uploaded.
Here's the pseudo code:

```
for file_ in vmdk_files:
    request.post(url, data=file, verify=False)
```